# Twilio converstation Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'myConversationsRead')

Tags: reactjs, twilio

Using Twilio JS SDK and and trying to access conversations throught `getConversationBySid()` method.

```
const client = new Client(tokenValue);
let value=await client.getConversationBySid(conversationSID)
```

but getting error
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'myConversationsRead')`
Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Hey i'm having the exact same issue, did you ever figure out what was causing it?

Answer (score 0):

This error is correct. You need to wait for client to initialise as is described in the docs.

https://sdk.twilio.com/js/conversations/releases/2.2.0/docs/classes/Client.html#constructor

Answer (score 0):

I think you may just need to wait for the client to initialize before using it. Code sample from the SDK docs:

```
const { Client } = require('@twilio/conversations');

const client = new Client(token);

// Before you use the client, subscribe to the `'initialized'` event.
client.on('initialized', () => {
  // Use the client.
}

// To catch client initialization errors, subscribe to the `'initFailed'` event.
client.on('initFailed', ({ error }) => {
  // Handle the error.
});
```

https://sdk.twilio.com/js/conversations/releases/2.2.0/docs/